# SQL complex selection

Tags: java, mysql, sql, resultset

I have to figure out a very complex selection.
No idea how this is possible, but I think it is.

---

There are two tables:

*threads*: primary key is the column 'thread_id'

*subscribes*: primary key is 'user' together with 'thread_id'

---

I need a selection that **selects** all threads **ordered by** how many people have subscribed to them.

---

**Example situation**:

There are *threads* with the ids 1 - 5 in the table 'threads'

*Subscribe* table looks like this:

```
user     thread_id
x        1
x        2
y        2
z        4
z        2
```

You can see, most subscribed thread is 2.
I want a selection that brings thread_id 2 first in its result, because 2 is the most subscribed one.

---

So can anyone help me? I tried for an hour but didn't find a solution

Comment: SUM(), GROUP BY , ORDER BY are your friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT thread_id, COUNT(*) AS cpt FROM subscribes GROUP BY thread_id ORDER BY cpt
```

Answer (score 1):

Just group on the thread_id field and get your counts accordingly. Won't take account of multiple bindings on the same user though, but that would be a constraint issue, if that were allowed on this table.

```
select thread_id, count(*) as thread_count from threads group by thread_id, order by thread_count desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use count and group by

```
select user, count(*) 
from Subscribe 
group by thread_id
order by thread_id;
```

Comment: It should be ordered_by and grouped_by thread_id to get the user count per thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your possible solution

```
SELECT
    s.thread_id, COUNT(DISTINCT s.user) AS total_subscribed
FROM    
    subscribes s
INNER JOIN threads t 
    ON s.thread_id = t.thread_id
GROUP BY
    s.thread_id 
ORDER BY
    total_subscribed DESC
```

You don't need DISTINCT if you have no duplicate user in a threds

Comment: To make ensure the thread_id I added join query with the two tables. You can use only subscribes table to getting the results.